Problema de duplicación de datos al importar herramientas desde un archivo Excel en Vue 3 y Laravel 8
soy desarollador web Jr, estoy en mi práctica profesional supervisada y es la primera vez que trabajo con Vue 3 y laravel 8.
Lo que sucede es que tengo una función de importar herramientas desde un archivo excel, sin embargo cada que la uso; y después de recargar de nuevo la página, la tabla con la lista de herramientas se muestra con entradas duplicadas e incluso con más de 10 copias, además ese fallo afecta las otras tablas dentro del proyecto que no tienen ninguna relación con el componente de importar. Esto no se ve reflejado en la base de datos en donde si se muestra la cantidad correcta de datos.
He de decir que ya revisé el código y no parece haber nada fuera de lugar, los ciclos que uso están bien configurados y la lógica no parece estar mal...
Para solucionarlo borré la base de datos de prueba y la creé de nuevo, todo sirve perfecto y se muestra bien, hasta que se usa de nuevo la función de importar.
Por favor, les agradecería mucho si me pudieran orientar en como solucionar este problema, con la experiencia que tengo sinceramente no sé que pueda ser.
Muchas gracias.

Agrega el código. Gracias.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
